# Kinect - no devices connected on openni_node.launch

Tags: ros, openni, turtlebot, openni-node, openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all, I'm starting with the turtlebot but can't get the Kinect to be recognized. I am runnig diamondback.

I redid `sudo apt-get install openni_kinect` just to make sure it was there, but didn't solve the problem.

Output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 13d3:3315 IMC Networks 
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 045e:02b0 Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0409:005a NEC Corp. HighSpeed Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 13d3:5702 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Output of roslaunch openni_camera openni_node.launch:

```
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://turtlebot-laptop:42441/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro
 * /openni_node1/use_indices
 * /openni_node1/depth_registration
 * /openni_node1/image_time_offset
 * /openni_node1/depth_frame_id
 * /openni_node1/depth_mode
 * /openni_node1/debayering
 * /rosversion
 * /openni_node1/projector_depth_baseline
 * /openni_node1/rgb_frame_id
 * /openni_node1/depth_rgb_translation
 * /openni_node1/depth_time_offset
 * /openni_node1/image_mode
 * /openni_node1/shift_offset
 * /openni_node1/device_id
 * /openni_node1/depth_rgb_rotation

NODES
  /
    openni_node1 (openni_camera/openni_node)
    kinect_base_link (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    kinect_base_link1 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    kinect_base_link2 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    kinect_base_link3 (tf/static_transform_publisher)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [22450]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.11:11311

setting /run_id to a30405ca-f056-11e0-83fc-5c260a051546
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [22463]
started core service [/rosout]
process[openni_node1-2]: started with pid [22473]
process[kinect_base_link-3]: started with pid [22476]
process[kinect_base_link1-4]: started with pid [22477]
process[kinect_base_link2-5]: started with pid [22478]
process[kinect_base_link3-6]: started with pid [22479]
[ INFO] [1317931571.886741090]: [/openni_node1] No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[ INFO] [1317931572.887058521]: [/openni_node1] No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[ INFO] [1317931573.887393253]: [/openni_node1] No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12107/kinect---no-devices-connected-on-openni_node.launch/) by [chopchop](https://answers.ros.org/users/1448/chopchop/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2011-11-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
lsusb should give 3 devices of Microsoft as below.

```
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 045e:02ae Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 045e:02ad Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 045e:02b0 Microsoft Corp.
```

I mean this is not w r t turtlebot, but in general when connecting Kinect using external power supply. When its disconnected from external supply it gives the one device as in your case.

Thanks,
Karthik

---

Originally posted by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) with karma: 2831 on 2011-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chopchop](https://answers.ros.org/users/1448/chopchop/) on 2011-11-27**:
Thanks I needed to set the mode to Full in the turtlebot dashboard in order to power up the Kinect.